# How can i solve the following error while run the app : Could not resolve all files for configuration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, ecmascript-6

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-camera:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
12 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 11 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: what is the build command you are running. as it says adding `--stacktrace` to that may help. something like (assuming package.json/npm etc) - `npm run build --stacktrace` or in the scripts - `<BUILD-PACKAGE> --stacktrace [options]`

Comment: If this did help it would be really nice if you marked the submitted answer below as such.

Answer (score 0):

what is the build command you are running. as it says adding `--stacktrace` to that may help. something like (assuming package.json/npm etc) - `npm run build --stacktrace` or in the scripts - `<BUILD-PACKAGE> --stacktrace [options]`

package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "makeItSo": "<BUILD-PACKAGE> --stacktrace [options]"
    }
}
```